# wildcard search in notepad++ to get particular line if it matches any string between first and last search except whitespaces

Tags: regex, notepad++

1. `this is sample text jfhwkjefwl todo`
2. `here sample text todo`
3. `sample text todo`

I want to select only the first statement `"this is sample text jfhwkjefwl todo"`. I tried with different combination of `[t][e][x][t].*[t][o][d][o]` and `[t][e][x][t ].*[t][o][d][o]`.

can one help me will be most appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
.*text\s+\S+\s+todo.*
```

Means anything optional (`.*`) followed by "text" followed by at least one whitespace (`\s+`) followed by at least one non-whitespace (`\S+`) followed by at least one whitespace followed by "todo".
So if you want to match the whole line then your regex have to match everything you want and not only a substring.

Answer (score 1):

I would sugeest a similar approach to [Odog's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67716228/7505395) but with a twist: lazy capturing instead of greedy:

```
text\s+\S+?\s+todo    # non greeedy search, until first todo
```

instead of

> text\s+\S+\s+todo    # greeedy search, until last todo

Lazy capturing matches until the first `todo` - not the last of a line. In notepad++ a non-greedy search (see 2nd match) would look like this:

[image: screenshot of notepad++ with search dialog settings]